# Find width of a rectangle around a smaller rectangle

Tags: geometry

A garden plot must have a central planting area of length 13 m and width 8 m. There is to be a sidewalk around its edge of width w. If the total area, planting area plus sidewalk area, is 144 m^2, what is the sidewalk width w in meters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the bigger rectangle is $13+2x$ meters and the width is $8 + 2x$ meters. We know the area and now we do a simle calculation:

$$(13 + 2x)(8 + 2x) = 144$$
$$104 + 16x + 26x + 4x^2 = 144$$
$$4x^2 + 42x = 40$$

We just need the positive solution which is:

$$x = \frac{\sqrt{601} - 21}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks so much! I got close to that but I had some math errors.

Comment: You're welcome :D

Comment: The quadratic equation should be $4x^2 +\mathbf{42} x = 40$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Draw a picture. You can see that the total region has length $13+2w$ and width $8+2w$. It follows that
$$(2w+13)(2w+8)=144.$$
Now you can use general techniques: the equation, when you expand, is a nice quadratic equation. Solve, say by using the Quadratic Formula. There will be two solutions, but one is easily discarded.

**Added:** When you expand, you will get $4w^2+42w-40=0$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to find the area of the outside rectangle only from that, but the above answer explains it. Thanks.

Comment: You know the outer rectangle is $13+2w$ by $8+2w$. The area is the product.

Comment: thanks. that explains it better